# Disabling or removing the close button from uwp app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Universal app does not allow to remove or disable the close button it seems. We can hide it by going full screen. But when moving cursor over it, brings title bar back. Is there any way to remove the close button?

Reason : I am working on screen time. After allowed time gets over, I want to block the screen. I should remove close button so that user cant get over my app.

Edit : Removing close button wont help completely. It is a part of work. I am just asking how to remove it.

Comment: Even if you managed to remove the close button, the user could still switch apps using alt + tab, ctrl + alt + del, close it using alt + f4, or simply open the start menu

Comment: @KooKiz yeah.. I knew it. I need to handle that too. But I got struck in first step itself.

Comment: BlockInput function helps us to block mouse and keyboard. But ctrl + alt + del is exceptional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With current released API, we are able to customize the color of these three buttons in title bar. But there is no property or method could be used to disable or remove these buttons.

In UWP, we can use [ApplicationView.TitleBar | titleBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.titlebar.aspx) to get the title bar like following:

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
```

This property's type is [ApplicationViewTitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewtitlebar.aspx). It only has several properties that can customize the button's color like:

```
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.White;
```

Using these properties may make the close button invisible like:
[image]

However this won't actually hide these buttons. Users can still minimize or maximize the app and when the pointer is over the top right corner, they will still see the close button.
[image]

From Windows 8.1, if we want users to use only an application and do nothing else including closing the application, we can use **Kiosk Mode**. For more info, please see [Enable Kiosk Mode in Windows 8.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hyperyash/2013/10/24/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1/) and [Set up a kiosk on Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions#set-up-assigned-access-in-pc-settings). However this won't meet your requirement as you want to block the screen after allowed time gets over.

So UWP may not be the best choice for your requirement. You may try to implement it with classic desktop apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the discover of Kiosk Mode in Windows.  I have never heard about this mode but it looks like the answer for my needs :)

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10 version 1703 (build 10.0.15063) and beyond, you can prevent the app from closing, using the SystemNavigationManagerPreview class.

Add this to your app manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
</Capabilities
```

You need to have the rescap namespace at the Package element:

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

In the constructor of your main form, add:

```
var sysNavMgr = SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView();
sysNavMgr.CloseRequested += OnCloseRequested;
```

OnCloseRequested can be implemented as follows:

```
    private void OnCloseRequested(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.GetDeferral();
        e.Handled = true;
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

Comment: Under <Capabilities> we should keep the order of elements as 'Capability', 'rescap:Capability', then 'DeviceCapability'. to get over compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

in App.Xaml.cs add this code :

```
     // Collapse Title bar 
    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(null);
    ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Version

```html
    // COLLAPSE THE TITLE BAR
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::GetCurrentView()->TitleBar->ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    Window::Current->SetTitleBar(nullptr);
    Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView^ view = Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
    view->TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```