# Disable close button in UWP TittleBar

Tags: uwp

In UWP,

Is there any way to disable or stop the functionality of close button in the tittle bar.
I do know that we can change the color but on changing the color functionality remains unchanged.
So i am looking for functionality as well.

Actual Problem : I am opening a non-UWP(Ex : Myapp) application from uwp. 
I will close  MYAPP and then only i should access to UWP app.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling or removing the close button from uwp app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497929/disabling-or-removing-the-close-button-from-uwp-app)

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion in my below reply?

Answer (score 1):

From the Windows 10 Creators Update(introduced v10.0.15063.0), there's a new [SystemNavigationManagerPreview Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview). You could handle its [CloseRequested Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested) to achieve your target.

Please note that if you want to make this API work, you would need to add [confirmAppClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) restricted capability in Package.appxmanifest file.

```
<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
```

Please see this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/UWP%20Systray/SystrayExtension/MainPage.xaml.cs#L33) for more details.